# Разметка не отображается в визуальном редакторе

Tags: android, android-studio

Создал проект на шаблоне Navigation Drawer. Если переключить SDK на 15 - то вообще все на дизайне исчезает даже макет телефона! В чем проблема? Теперь выскакивает ошибка:

> Couldn't resolve resource @style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode (2 similar errors not shown) The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate: 
>   - PorterDuff Color Filters are not supported. (Ignore for this session) 
>   Ignore all fidelity warnings for this session

Comment: Вы имеете в виду предпросмотрощик разметки? Если да, то не пользуйтесь им и протестируйте на реальном устройстве/эмуляторе.

Comment: Я еще ничего не добавил, да и добавлю один текст в XML, потом проверять на эмуляторе на моем тормознутом ноуте вообще один текст, по моему глупо!

Comment: Всё таки проверьте как я написал. Высока вероятность того, что проблема только в предпросмоторщике. И врядли, если так, её можно решить нетривиальным способом.

Comment: предпросмотрщик к сожалению творение довольно глючное и любящее последние 3 target SDK, то есть 21, 22 и 23. Но и на них частенько подглючивает. Попробуйте ещё темку какуюнить материальную в нем поставить а не Holo Light.